# Ruby on Rails url changes but view does not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I've been studying Ruby on Rails for a a few months and am going through the Hartl tutorial a second time for extra practice. In both development and production environments all links to the root url on my website place the correct url in the browser but do not load the view. The correct view loads only when I hit the refresh button after clicking one of the links to the root url. I think this may be a problem with the turbolinks gem but I'm not sure.

When looking at the server logs after clicking a link to the root url no error messages appear, just a log of the static pages/partials rendered, and followed users/micropost information. Further, when I hit the refresh button and the view loads correctly, the server log is exactly the same as when I click any of the links to the root url for the first time.

I thought it would be easier for everyone to see something that I may have missed if I just link to my git repository instead of posting the individual files: https://bitbucket.org/corourke24/sample_app2

Any advice or help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Edit: MarsAtomic suggested it would be easier if I showed an example of the link not working. The main links to the root url are in the header partial:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Caturday Surprise!", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here is my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'sessions/new'


  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/help',     to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',    to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact',  to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',   to: 'users#new'
  post   '/signup',   to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',    to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',    to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',   to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Here is my static_pages/home file(root url):

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'shared/logged_in_home' %>
<% else %>
    <%= render 'shared/logged_out_home' %>
<% end %>
```

Here are the partials that it renders:

logged_in_home:

```
<div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-4">
        <section class="user_info">
            <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
        </section>
        <section class="stats">
            <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
        </section>
        <section class="micropost_form">
            <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3>Micropost feed</h3>
        <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

logged_out_home:

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
    <h1>Caturday Surprise</h1>

    <h2>
        This is the home page for 
        <a href="http://cat-bounce.com/">Cats!</a>
        (a sample application).
    </h2>
        <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
<div class="center">
    <%= link_to image_tag("kitten.jpg", alt: "Kitten picture",
                           title: "All cats matter"),
                            'http://iheartcats.com/' %>

    <%= link_to image_tag("cute-kitten.jpg", alt: "Cute kitten picture", 
                          title: "Random kittens generator"), 
                          'http://www.randomkittengenerator.com/' %>
</div>
```

This is the logged_in? method from my sessions_helper file:

```
def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end
```

Comment: Rather than having people wade through your repo digging through unfamiliar code, maybe you could provide an example of where you use your non-refreshing link_to. This problem is probably not Turbolinks. The classic problem with Turbolinks is that scripts don't run without a refresh, as opposed to not displaying a page at all.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Thanks for clearing things up for me about Turbolinks. I've added what I think should be all of the necessary files to illustrate what is going on to my question. Let me know if you think I should add anything else to make it easier to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Keep in mind I'm not 100% certain about Turbolinks -- your symptoms just don't fit the classical pattern. Try removing the turbolinks gem and you'll have your answer for sure. I can't really think of a reason why you're seeing what you're seeing...

Comment: I like to keep code clean and neat and I am not seeing that at all in your routes.rb file. Why not use the Devise gem to help you start cleaning up those routes? And I don't think you are using partials in the way they were meant to be used. The purpose of your partial is to write the code once, not two or three different versions once.